# Temporarily override constraints

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have an iPad view that contains a subview which is constrained by autolayout, its height is different depending on if device is landscape or portrait.

The bottom of this subview is fixed via constraints 25 from the bottom of main view.

When keyboard appears I shrink the view, which obviously breaks the 25 constraint.

Currently to revert the view (when keyboard disappears) I change the height back to the original value (before keyboard appeared).

Problem is if I then rotate the iPad, the height of the subview doesn't auto size correctly, as the 25 constraint is turned off.

I know I can put logic into viewwillrotate and programatically set the height each rotation but this feels ugly.

If there a way I can set the height of the item so it ignores me override its height and sets itself so it satisfies the constraints?

Comment: Share your code please.

Comment: In a simplified way: you can add twice the constraints. One for one case, the second for the other case. Whenever you need it, you can switch there `.isActive` value.

Comment: You can listen for keyboard notifications, and follow Larme's suggestion to toggle the `.isActive` property